# How do you search with TransactionSearch?

Tags: c#, netsuite

How do you find a Vendor Payment (Transaction) with an Vendor Payment internal id?
I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how Transaction search work.

Below is my code: it return success but no result

```
using (var serviceClient = new ServiceClient(token))
        {
            var tranSearch = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();

            var recordRefs = new List<RecordRef>();
            recordRefs.Add(new RecordRef()
            {
                internalId = @"723212",
                type = RecordType.vendorPayment,
                typeSpecified = true
            });

            var types = new List<string>();
            types.Add(@"_vendorPayment");
            tranSearch.criteria = new TransactionSearch()
            {
                basic = new TransactionSearchBasic()
                {
                    internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField()
                    {
                        @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                        operatorSpecified = true,
                        searchValue = recordRefs.ToArray()
                    },
                    type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField()
                    {
                        @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
                        operatorSpecified = true,
                        searchValue = types.ToArray()
                    }                        
                }                    

            };                

            var result = serviceClient.search(tranSearch);



        }
```

The search result return success however there is no record in recordlist or search in searchrowlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of `TransactionSearchAdvanced()` like a saved search in the UI.  You need to specify the criteria to use AND the columns that you want to return. Before you run your search, add the following code to specify the columns to return.  You'll probably want to add a criteria for mainLine is `true` as well or you'll get one result per transaction line rather than one result per transaction.

```
tranSearch.columns = new TransactionSearchRow()
{
    basic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic()
    {
        tranId = new[] {new SearchColumnStringField()}
    }
};

var result = ns.search(tranSearch);

if (result.status.isSuccess)
{
    foreach (var rowList in result.searchRowList)
    {
        if (rowList is TransactionSearchRow row)
        {
            var tranId = row.basic.tranId[0].searchValue;
            var total = row.basic.total[0].searchValue;
            Console.WriteLine($"{tranId} - {total}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Easiest Method**: Since you have the internal ID, you can use `TransactionSearchBasic()` to get the entire record like this:

```
var search = new TransactionSearchBasic()
{
    type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField()
    {
        @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        searchValue = new[] { "_vendorPayment" },
        operatorSpecified = true,
    },
    internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField()
    {
        @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        searchValue = new[] { new RecordRef { internalId = "723212" } },
        operatorSpecified = true
    }
};

var results = ns.search(search);

foreach (var result in results.recordList)
{
    if (result is VendorPayment vendorPayment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(vendorPayment.tranId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still getting 0 records. Is there some kind of permission that you need to set? I'm using the token auth.

Comment: It doesn't sound like permissions to me.  If you didn't have permissions to the vendorPayment record, you would receive a message something like "Your role does not give you permissions to view this page."  If you're getting no results, is it possible that you've got the wrong internal ID?  If I put the incorrect internal id, the search is successful, but no rows are returned.

Comment: app/accounting/transactions/vendpymt.nl?id=723212&whence=. Isn't the internal id 723212 for this vendor payment? I have internal id turn on so when i go to Bill Payment. it have a list of internal id next to the Bill Payment record. i also use the id from the url. unless i'm mistaken but isn't Bill Payment = Vendor Payment?

Comment: Yes.  That's the internal ID.

Comment: that's why i'm not getting it. it seem like i should be able to get Vendor payment record based on the internal id but there is no record return. its interesting that if i use _vendorBill without specific a internal id. i can get 1000 records back. that's why i think is there some kind of permission that need to be set.

Comment: It turns out that with token authentication, you don't get the same permission error you get with the older credentials-based authentication, so it may very well be a permissions problem.  Make sure the role that you're using has the Pay Bills permission on the Transaction tab.  Turning this on and off gives me results or not, but no error either way.

Comment: Yup Pay Bills fix it. LOL. Thank you for all your help